Woman sees her reflection in window and then most likely stabs her husband
Okay, I have searched literally anything to find this movie, but I am stuck. 
I think it has some possession/witch/haunting involved, but I am not sure. 
All I know is that it ends with a woman standing in the kitchen, (you can see wedding photos of her and the other main character on the fridge, suggesting that they got married after the whole mess was over). She cooks dinner, and her husband comes in and they share a cute moment. 
Before he leaves (probably to get ready for dinner) everything seems fine, until we see the woman from behind, looking up and through the window in front of her. Then her whole attitude changes, she takes the knife in her hand and walks out of the kitchen.
It was pretty obvious that she was going to kill him. 
And then the movie ends, leaving this enormous twist.
I don't think the movie was that good, but the ending changed everything. 
I hope I managed to describe it enough, and hopefully someone other than me has seen this movie! Thank you for any feedback.
The movie is not from the years 2015-2017 

Welcome to the site. Was the film in English or another language? Do you know what country it was produced in?

So it's prior to 2015, but how much prior? Did it look a bit dated, or more like a recent movie? Can you remember what the man and woman looked like?
